# going through array assembly PDP-11(Pascal-triangle)

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

I'm new to assembler and has a task to write a program that creates pascal triangle, when i get a number N that indicates the depth of the triangle.
the question defines to do that by a two-dimension array.

output for example:

1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 2 1 0

etc.

I'm allowed to use only memory that's indicated in the question and use registers.
my question is: how can i access the previous cells to calculte the current cell, without losing the current location?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If your items are sequential in memory, then (starting with the 3rd row) you can access `p-N` and `p-N-1` for the two elements to sum up (`p` is pointer to current item, scale offset by item size).

Comment: In order to access adress of "p-N", is should use adressing mode 67? and if so, how can i calculate the EA? using @(r7-r4-1), r1 doesn't work for me.

Comment: You will need to perform the subtraction separately into a scratch register.

Comment: x86 (and generic arch-independent indexing math) duplicate: [algorithm of addressing a triangle matrices memory using assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49165711)